# DataFrame : Set User defined values while grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
            user user_id age           swiped_in           swiped_out
        0    Bob       1  53  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2018-02-25 10:50:32
        1   Jane       2  34  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2019-02-25 11:50:32
        2  Alice       3  35  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2019-02-25 12:50:32
        3    Bob       1  54  2019-02-25 10:50:32  2019-02-25 11:30:32
        4    Bob       1  55  2019-02-25 11:31:32  2019-02-25 12:51:32
        5   Jane       2  34  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2019-02-25 11:50:32
```

And this is my code..

```
c = ['swiped_in','swiped_out']
df[c] = df[c].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df = df.sort_values(c)   
df=df.groupby(['user','user_id']).agg({'swiped_in':'min','swiped_out':'max','age':'first'})
```

And now I can get the following output.

```
                swiped_in          swiped_out age
user  user_id                                            
Alice 3       2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 12:50:32  35
Bob   1       2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 12:51:32  53
Jane  2       2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 11:50:32  34
```

And what I need is..

```
         swiped_in          swiped_out age
user  user_id                                            
Alice 3       2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 12:50:32  35
Bob   1       2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 12:51:32  ..
Jane  2       2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 11:50:32  34
```

If the age is same then I can fill the data as it is. If it's not unique I need to put my customised value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the groupby part:

```
custom_value=5 #change this
df_new=(df.groupby(['user','user_id'])
        .agg({'swiped_in':'min','swiped_out':'max','age':
              lambda x:np.where(x.nunique()==1,next(iter(set(x))),custom_value)}))
print(df_new)


                       swiped_in          swiped_out  age
user  user_id                                             
Alice 3       2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 12:50:32   35
Bob   1       2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 12:51:32    5
Jane  2       2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 11:50:32   34
```

Comment: Hi @anky_91, It's working fine. Thank you.. If I have more than 10 columns to do the same operations means which one will be the right way(Other operations will be there for aggregation).

Comment: may be you can write a customised function. nut agg works fine